# Open Ears API says every sound it hears is a word, even a cough

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, openears

I am trying to use Open Ears for small part of my app.  I have three or four keywords that I want to be able to "listen" to.  Something like "Add", "Subtract", etc.  I am just using the sample app [found here.](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)  I want to have a special case in the app when I here "Add" etc. as opposed to a word that is not one of my four keywords.  Right now I set my language to be only the four keywords, but whenever the Open Ears API hears anything, it picks between my four keywords.  So if I cough, it picks the closest word out of the four words

How can I listen for a specific word without always choosing one of the keywords?

I was thinking I could have a whole bunch of words, a few hundred, and just check which word was spoken, and have a special case for my four keywords, but I don't want to have to type down each word.  Does Open ears provide any default languages?

Answer (score 4):

OpenEars developer here. Check out the dynamic grammar generation API that was just added in OpenEars 1.7 which may provide the right results for your requirements: http://www.politepix.com/2014/04/10/openears-1-7-introducing-dynamic-grammar-generation/

This approach might be more suitable for keyword detection and detection of fixed phrases. Please bring further questions to the OpenEars forums if you'd like to troubleshoot them with me.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  This looks like it is perfect.  If I have problems, I'll head over to those forums.